# Understanding FME error?

Tags: csv, fme-form

When I launch a treatment on FME 2018 the following message will appear :

> CSV reader: Detected excess data and/or delimiters in addition to the
>   defined schema in line XXXX

Note that the treatment works very well, I am just wondering how I got this message, is there a limit of tuples imposed by FME in the .csv reader ?

Comment: can you give an example of the 'treatment' csv file? how is the csv generated?

Comment: the header needs to match number of fields needs to match the commas and quotes (,'text',) >sometimes there are commas and quotes in the fields themselves that can cause errors reading csv.

Comment: Yeah I think this may be caused by the file structure. The file only has one column of which I take substrings to create new attributes with.

Comment: It sounds like there is a comma in at least one line that is causing FME to think that there are multiple columns in it. If it's just a single like of text, then try the Text File reader instead of CSV. It won't have that issue because it won't try to split up the data. Or - if the data is column-aligned - try the CAT (Column-Aligned Text) reader.

Comment: To add, my concern would be that the line in question would/could be truncated because of this, so even if the workspace runs to completion, it's something you should probably fix.

Answer (score -1):

Can you check your CSV file please? I think that you have something like this
A;B;C;D
5;5;5;4;8 
The information 8 has no column and that will give you the error mentioned above (not really an error because it is not in red as I think). Be careful because the information 8 will not be written in the output.